# Get the file system type that a file is stored on

Tags: c, bash, unix

How can I determine the type of file-system that a file is stored on?  I might have the filename, or later, just a descriptor.

I would happily use a script at first, but would like *also* to know how to do it with syscalls from C.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the command line/script, You can use `stat`:

```
$ stat -f -c "%T" someFileOnExt2Ext3
ext2/ext3

$ stat -f -c "%T" someFileOnNFS
nfs
```

This eventually leads to the [statfs(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/statfs) system call:

```
int statfs(const char *path, struct statfs *buf);
```

> The function statfs() returns information about a mounted file system.
>   path is the pathname of any file within the mounted file system, buf
>   is a pointer to a statfs structure.